# How do I get a filter to let through the fields I specify?

Tags: support, api-v2, filter

I've created a filter based on the "none" filter with include fields for all those I will need for my application. While the [filter I created](http://bit.ly/xebF8v) looks fine to me, it doesn't appear to return any results against any of the API endpoints I use: [sites](http://bit.ly/yXoNYf), [questions](http://bit.ly/zwCFeN), or [users](http://bit.ly/yC44xb).

Since I barely use what is sent back, I would love to get filters working. Am I missing some core concept to getting filters to work?

Comment: Try visiting [this page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) and carefully examining the URL used to make the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning `.items`, which contains the objects that have the fields you want back.

When you include it you get `!*QjqSxwBvapC)EVC)JW_Vhi*w4jvF.WzEYmxBpMaH`, which does return values for [/sites](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#filter=!%2aQjqSxwBvapC%29EVC%29JW_Vhi%2aw4jvF.WzEYmxBpMaH&run=true), [/questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!%2aQjqSxwBvapC%29EVC%29JW_Vhi%2aw4jvF.WzEYmxBpMaH&site=stackoverflow&run=true), and [/users](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!%2aQjqSxwBvapC%29EVC%29JW_Vhi%2aw4jvF.WzEYmxBpMaH&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: Well, I feel stupid now. Thank you so much for taking the time to get me going in the right direction. That ought to cut down the data over the wire for my app quite a bit. BTW, I absolutely love this concept in an API.

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, these filter-included URLs don't work with markdown directly (had to shorten them first). I put it [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/118739/stackapps-com-api-urls-not-rendered-as-links), but I am guessing it's by design for some of the funky characters they include.